# How make correct highlight custom useHook writen in JS?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, react-hooks, syntax-highlighting

I use VS Code for writing custom project in React.

When I wrote useState the value and callback correctly highlighted, cause exist *.d.ts

But if I write custom hook `useOfferObserver` in JS, can I add any specification to my function for correct highlight?

I want that `setFieldData` has the same color as `setFormError`

```js
export const useOfferObserver = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriberID = uuidv4()
    offerDL.subscribe(subscriberID, () => setCount(count + 1))
    return () => offerDL.unSubscribe(subscriberID)
  }, [])

  return [offerDL, (data) => {
    console.log('Data should be updated', data)
  }]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what has the wrong color, what is the type of `useState` and `useOfferObserver` using the tooltip, what is the TextMate scope of the things correct and incorrect colored

Comment: @rioV8 I add to question: I want that setFieldData has the same color as setFormError

I haven't use TextMate

Comment: What are the types of `setFieldData` and `setFormError` according to the tooltips, if it is not syntax highlighting it is semantic highlighting, find out the difference in semantic scope

Comment: @rioV8 the different I explained: useState has index.d.ts where this function is fixed typed. I add the screenshot. useOfferObserver is written in JS, not TypeScript it is why the color is different. And my question may be I can add any correct comment to function header and VS can understood the parameters types.

Comment: yes, look at the tooltip of the function, it should show its type, your function returns an array with the second index a `void` function, `useState` returns a `Dispatch<...>` (why post an image from a text file) as second result, You can add JSDOC to your JavaScript function to guide the intellisense

Comment: @rioV8 the last comments about JSDoc looks like answer for my request. Will try. Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @rioV8 comments I found the resolution.

It is add JSDoc for my custom hook.

```js
/**
* This callback is displayed as part of the Requester class.
* @callback SetterCallback
* @param {object} data
*/
/**
* @returns {[offerData: Object, setter: SetterCallback]}
*/
export const useOfferObserver = () => {
  const [, setTime] = useState(performance.now())

  return [offerDL, (data, skipBackendRequest = false) => {
    return offerDL.update(data, skipBackendRequest)
      .then(() => setTime(performance.now()))
  }]
}
```

after that my hooks has correct highlight.

[image]